# subset a matrix, and get NA if index is not valid

Tags: r, matrix, subset

I am trying to subset a matrix to always get a 3*3 matrix.

For example, the matrix being subset is `a<-matrix(1:15,3,5)`, usually when I subset it using `a[0:2,0:2]`, I get:

```
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5
```

But I want to get something like:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA    NA   NA
[2,]   NA    1    4
[3,]   NA    2    5
```

Comment: Well, do be fair `a[rep(1:3, each=5), rep(1:5, each=3)]` is "subsetting" but results in a larger matrix. The real problem is that R doesn't like to use 0 as indices. Compare: `x<-1:5; x[0]; x[6]`

Comment: One alternative is to create `newmat<-matrix(NA,3,3)` and then fill all or part of it with the data you're extracting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Force all your `0`'s to `NA`s when you select, as well as any 'out-of-bounds' values:

```
ro <- 0:2
co <- 0:2
a[replace(ro,ro == 0 | ro > nrow(a),NA),
  replace(co,co == 0 | co > ncol(a),NA)]

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   NA   NA   NA
#[2,]   NA    1    4
#[3,]   NA    2    5
```

This will even work with combinations of the parts you want missing:

```
ro <- c(1,0,2)
co <- 0:2
a[replace(ro,ro == 0 | ro > nrow(a),NA),
  replace(co,co == 0 | co > ncol(a),NA)]

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   NA    1    4
#[2,]   NA   NA   NA
#[3,]   NA    2    5
```

Comment: Perhaps you could, also, add `ro == 0 | ro > nrow(a)` (and for columns, too) to cover any "subscript out of bounds" error.

Comment: Thanks thelatemail and alexis_laz! This is the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own padding function to fill in space less than 3x3 by NA values

```
padmatrix <- function(a, dim=c(3,3)) {
    stopifnot(all(dim(a)<=dim))
    cbind(rep(NA,dim[2]-ncol(a)), rbind(rep(NA,dim[1]-nrow(a)), a))
}

padmatrix(a[1:2, 1:2])
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   NA   NA   NA
# [2,]   NA    1    4
# [3,]   NA    2    5
```